# RAA Proof using conditionals

Tags: logic

I am having trouble trying to prove the following using RAA.

$(G∙P)→K,$

$E→Z,$

$~P→~Z,$

$G→(E \lor L),$

$\text{___________}$

$\therefore (G∙~L) →K$

I have already proved it using the conditional proof method, and was trying to prove it using RAA to show that it could be done with both.

Comment: Assume the negation of the conclusion...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I am familiar with the procedure of doing an RAA proof. I assumed the negation of the conclusion and have, unsuccessfully, used other equivalence rules to try and reach a contradiction. I was more asking for help in doing the problem, since I am clearly not seeing the correct path.

Comment: The negation of the conclusion is $(G \land \lnot L) \land \lnot K$ from which we have $\lnot K$ and $G \land \lnot L$. Thus, in order to produce a contradiction, we may try to derive $K$.

Comment: From $G \land \lnot L$ we have $G$ and from 4th premise: $E \lor L$. With $\lnot L$ we get $E$ and from 2nd premise $Z$. With it and 3rd premise we get $P$. Now we have both $G$ and $P$ and we can finally use 1st premise.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA Thank you for your insight. I was trying to do it only negating K and was unsuccessful in my attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can prove it by conditional proof, of course you may prove it by reduction to absurdity.

When you assume the negation, then you may obviously derive a contradiction *using the conditional proof*.

$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\\\fitch{(G\cdot P)\to K\\E\to Z\\\neg P\to\neg Z\\G\to(E\vee L)}{\fitch{\neg((G\cdot\neg L)\to K)}{\left.{\raise{2ex}{\fitch{G\cdot\neg L}{~\vdots\\K}\\(G\cdot \neg L)\to K}}\right\}\\\bot}\\\neg\neg((G\cdot \neg L)\to K)\\\hspace{-4ex}\therefore\hspace{2ex}(G\cdot\neg L)\to K}$$

This is why reduction to absurdity should only be attempted as a last resort -- if a direct proof is possible, then a RAA proof will contain redundancy.

Comment: I agree. The point of the question was that things can be done many different ways and to show how a conclusion can be derived using different methods of proof solving. Thank you for your response!